# Appstore, turn off password for free apps download?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

is there a way to turn off the password requirement when downloading free content from the appstore?

I just find it slightly annoying when other app marketplaces don't have that compulsory requirement

did not google, thanks for doing it for me while I type my password

Comment: The App Store behaves differently on OS X and Windows and iOS so it's not clear what device you hope to manage or if you are asking if there is a cloud setting to disable it on your account

Answer (score 4):

No, there’s no way to do that on a clean iOS install.

However, if you don’t mind jailbreaking your iOS device, you can use [PasswordPilot](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/07/24/passwordpilot/) to auto-enter your App Store password.

Comment: I assume that would auto-enter the password for all purchases, and not just free purchases?

Comment: no jailbreak on 2012 ipad

Comment: @AdamDavis Yeah, me too.

Comment: @cqm Then you’re out of luck, until a jailbreak exploit is found for the new iPad. (Your question didn’t specify this was about a 2012 iPad.)